# How to differentiate elements in an XSD by namespaces

Tags: xml, xsd, namespaces, schema

Given the following XML snippet:

```
...
<ns1:Method>
  <Parameter1 />
  <Parameter2 />
</ns1:Method>

<ns2:Method>
  <Parameter3 />
</ns2:Method>
...
```

Is it possible to write an XML Schema definition, that differs the `complexType` of `Method` by its namespace, so that multiple different types named `Method` are possible?

In this example the `Method` element in namespace `ns1` should have 2 subelements and the element in namespace `ns2` should have only 1 subelement.

Comment: Element differentation **is** a purpose of the namespaces...

Comment: i know, that's why i already use it to query this document for those elements. but i can't get my head around writing a schema definition that uses those namespaces to validate those methods correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only is it possible to use namespaces to differentiate otherwise identically named components (including elements), it is the reason namespaces were created.

The target namespace of an XML Schema becomes a part of the name of every element defined in the XSD.  You can combined declarations from multiple XSDs with different namespaces via `xsd:import`.

Note, though, that while your different `Method` elements could be differentiated by namespaces, it may still be better differentiate the elements by their local name if possible:

```
<CalculateAreaMethod>
  <Height/>
  <Width/>
</CalculateAreaMethod>

<GetTemperatureMethod>
  <Location/>
</GetTemperatureMethod>
```

Finally, another option for differentiating element types based on attribute values is XSD 1.1's conditional type assignment, which would support this sort of naming:

```
<Method name="CalculateAreaMethod">
  <Height/>
  <Width/>
</Method>

<Method name="GetTemperatureMethod">
  <Location/>
</Method>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for your tip with the xsd:import and the targetNamespace. Those are the two keywords i was looking for. The solution is to extract the various elements in individual schema definitions (each with the unique targetNamespace defined) and import those in the parent schema. Am I right?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, but you would use one `xs:import` to bring in all definitions in each imported XSD, and you would have a separate `xs:import` for each distinct namespace.